# Update query with select and where clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm doing a little project for school is sql. I'm using MS Access as my database engine.

I'm trying to calculate and update Project Phases with the real end date of a phase by the last real end date of an assignment in that phase.
This query return me a prompt that ask me to enter a value for "meet.PhaseId".

```
UPDATE ProjectPhases 
SET RealEndDate = (SELECT MAX(asgn.RealEndDate) AS RealEndDate 
                   FROM Assignments AS asgn 
                   INNER JOIN 
                   (
                     Meetings AS meet 
                     INNER JOIN ProjectPhases 
                     ON meet.PhaseId = ProjectPhases.PhaseId
                   ) 
                     ON asgn.MeetingId = meet.MeetingId 
                   WHERE meet.PhaseId = ProjectPhases.PhaseId 
                    vAND asgn.RealEndDate IS NOT NULL) 
WHERE meet.PhaseId = ProjectPhases.PhaseId;
```

[image: Database structure (image)]

Comment: "not working" is not kind of description that will help you get valuable  answers. Try to be more precise in your problem description.

Comment: @Plirkee Tnx, I'm new here. edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider saving your aggregate query in a separate query and then use the domain aggregate, `DLookUp()` in the update query. In MS Access SQL (unlike other dialects), update queries must maintain the *updateable* condition (or non [read-only](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)) which rules out use of aggregate queries.

**SELECT query** *(no ProjectPhases join)*

```
SELECT meet.PhaseId, MAX(asgn.RealEndDate) AS MaxRealEndDate 
FROM Assignments AS asgn 
INNER JOIN Meetings AS meet 
ON asgn.MeetingId = meet.MeetingId 
WHERE asgn.RealEndDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY meet.PhaseId
```

**UPDATE query**

```
UPDATE ProjectPhases p
SET p.RealEndDate = DLookUp("MaxRealEndDate", "myaggQuery", "PhaseId=" & p.PhaseId)
```

---

Alternatively, you might consider a nested domain aggregate to avoid the saved aggregate query:

```
UPDATE ProjectPhases p
SET p.RealEndDate = DMax("RealEndDate", "Assignments", "MeetingId=" & 
                         DLookUp("MeetingId", "Meetings", "PhaseId=" & p.PhaseId) &
                         " AND RealEndDate IS NOT NULL")
```

Comment: So, it is not possible to do this thing in pure sql when using MS Access?

Comment: As mentioned, non-updateable queries which include aggregate queries cannot be used in update queries in the MS Access SQL dialect. Now, you can create a table of aggregate query results and then use an `UPDATE tbl INNER JOIN othertbls...SET` as this join is updateable and does not include `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't select *meet.PhaseId* from your subquery, thus no *PhaseId* exists to filter on.

It is often easier to build your query step by step using the GUI designer.

Comment: When i add PhaseId to the subquery i get "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field. (Error 3306)" 
I cant use the gui, the pint here is to learn sql

Comment: Your errors and questions are very basic, so use the GUI designer and study the SQL. And/or browse for a guide on SQL.